# Reloading selection of FBFriendsPicker ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have a `FBFriendsPicker` that allows user to select friends, that selection then stores into an array of my own, but I want to allow the user to see what friends he picked once he enters the `friendspicker` again. 
Right now the **V** signs next to the friends name disappear each time the the user presses **ok** or **cancel** thus each time starting the selection from scratch.

Here is what I have so far:

`selectedFriends` is the array. As you can see I tried to make an if statement that if user picked friends then show the user what he chose everytime he'll go into that `friendsPicker`
but the `friendPicker.selection` is a read-only property so I cant assign my array to it and i get a warning.

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPicker = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
        friendPicker.delegate = self;
        if ([selectedFriends count] > 0 )
        {
            friendPicker.selection = selectedFriends; //<--- NOT ASSIGNABLE
        }



        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil);
        ABPersonSortOrdering sortOrdering = ABPersonGetSortOrdering();
        ABPersonCompositeNameFormat nameFormat = ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat();

        friendPicker.sortOrdering = (sortOrdering == kABPersonSortByFirstName) ? FBFriendSortByFirstName : FBFriendSortByLastName;
        friendPicker.displayOrdering = (nameFormat == kABPersonCompositeNameFormatFirstNameFirst) ? FBFriendDisplayByFirstName : FBFriendDisplayByLastName;

        [friendPicker loadData];
        [friendPicker presentModallyFromViewController:self
                                              animated:YES
                                               handler:^(FBViewController *sender, BOOL donePressed) {
                                                   if (donePressed) {
                                                       selectedFriends = friendPicker.selection;
                                                       //   [self updateSelections];
                                                   }
                                               }];
        CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you debug the code of `FBFriendPickerViewController` you will find out that the `selection` property which is defined as a readonly `NSArray` actually is a `NSMutableArray`.

So what you can do is something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *selection = (NSMutableArray *) fbFriendPickerController.selection;

[selection removeAllObjects];

for (FBGraphObject *user in selectedFriends) {

    [selection addObject:user];
}
```

Comment: thats what I got trying : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeAllObjects]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb51a730'

Comment: That's strange. Mine is actually a `NSMutableArray` `(lldb) po self.selection
$0 = 0x11249710 <__NSArrayM 0x11249710>(` I'm using a version from earlier this year. Perhaps they have changed the implementation in later versions?

Comment: could be, i'm using 3.6, latest one